# Форма существительного при числительном в виде интервала

Tags: согласование, числительные

Можно ли говорить *3–5 месяцев* и *3–5 лет*? То есть для первой границы интервала необходимо существительное в форме единственного числа: *месяца* и *года*, а для второй — множественного числа: *месяцев* и *лет*.

Comment: Имеете в виду только устную речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно: **3–5 месяцев и 3–5 лет.**

Существительное согласуется с последнем числительным.

> [Вопрос № 293144](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=293144%20%20%20%20)
>   Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как правильно склонять существительные после интервала чисел, например: в хвойных лесах Томской области встречается 45-52 (вида или видов) птиц. Заранее спасибо!
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Здесь верно: вида. Возможно также: от 45 до 52 видов.